# Is it okay to use a colon within a bulleted list?

Tags: orthography, lists, colons, typography

Question 1: Are colons  allowed in a list?

> - Business writing skills: data entry, email, presentation and press release writing.

Question 2: Should there be only one *and* in a sentence?

Comment: I like the second question as I often wounder that myself.

Answer (score 1):

## Question the First

Regarding the presence of colons in a list, it is customary, particularly when prefaced with *the following*, to introduce an enumerated list of items with a colon, such as we do in the following list:

- Gigantic utterances: *fie*, *fie*, *foe*, and *fum*.

---

## Question the Second

Regarding the number of instances of the word *and* which are  permissible within a sentence, I prefer to produce citations from literature instead of fabricating unnatural sentences of my own devising, as these may be artificial and<sup>1</sup> unrealistic, even if unbeknownst to me.  I shall therefore cite from [Steven Brust’s most excellent homage to Alexander Dumas and<sup>1</sup> his fabulous musketeers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khaavren_Romances).

### A sentence with one *and*:

You are quite correct that having just  a single *and* — and<sup>1</sup> no more — is certainly allowed.  Witness this fine example:

> We are following the lives of certain personages, **and**<sup>1</sup> some of them, indeed,
>   were involved in these great events, but it is only in the course of
>   following these characters that we are witnessing the Disaster; at the
>   point when we began this tale, in fact, we, knowing where we would end, made
>   the decision to summarily omit any references to children, babies, or even
>   pets (with the exception of certain unimportant fishes) who may have come
>   to our attention—it is possible that the reader may have noticed the omission.

As you see, it is quite fine to have a sentence containing a single *and*, as you and<sup>1</sup> the esteemed Mr Brust have demonstrated.   But stay! There seems to be another example under my fingertips, one that is in fact . . .

### A sentence with two *and*s:

> While Khaavren sleeps the sleep of the young **and**<sup>1</sup> brave, we must, like the
>   hawk, whose eyes can see through the overcast to spot a norska who can not
>   see him, even should the norska think to look up, send our gaze winging
>   through the city, up Kieron’s Hill, past the Jungle of Ferns where Tuorli
>   sat for week after week composing a cycle of love-poems to her errant lover
>   the Marquis of Gweththor, Dzur Heir to the fifteenth throne, lost his
>   future **and**<sup>2</sup> his life in the six-hour-long duel with his cousin the Duke of
>   Kl’burra, until we arrive at an unprepossessing hostelry built of arched
>   wood on the Avenue of Urtiya the Sage.

And<sup>1</sup> while there you have an example of two, perhaps this is a mere aberration and<sup>2</sup> not something to be done lightly nor often.  Surely one could not envision . . .

### A sentence with three *and*s:

> In the long, complex, **and**<sup>1</sup> mysterious history of Sethra Lavode, the
>   historian doubts that she ever performed an act more courageous, more
>   difficult, **and**<sup>2</sup> more vital than, with full knowledge of what was about to
>   happen, standing in the Portrait room **and**<sup>3</sup> sending the Orb to the one place
>   in all the world where she knew, however all-encompassing the impending
>   disaster proved, even should it destroy every speck of life on the word
>   (which, in fact, she was not certain was not the case) the Orb, at least,
>   would be safe; in other words, to the Paths of the Dead.

I have looked and<sup>1</sup> looked, and<sup>2</sup> then looked some more, but I can find no fault with its grammar and<sup>3</sup> its syntax.  Passing strange it is; surely there can be no room for . . .

### A sentence with four *and*s:

> With complete confidence in the Teckla, Khaavren gave no more thought to 
>   the tasks he had assigned this worthy; instead he simply returned home, where 
>   his sword **and**<sup>1</sup> cloak were taken by Cyl, an elderly servant who had been with
>   the Manor since before the Interregnum, **and**<sup>2</sup> who, by this time, understood 
>   the complex relationships between imperial service, county service, **and**<sup>3</sup>
>   family life better than did any of the others who lived there, particularly
>   including the Countess **and**<sup>4</sup> Lord Khaavren.

As you can see, things have gotten out of hand here — but have they gotten out of *and*s as well?  Apparently not, for here is . . .

### A sentence with five *and*s:

> That, having accomplished this feat of unheard-of skill **and**<sup>1</sup> daring she
>   then, for no reason other than friendship, remained where she was long
>   enough to collect Aliera **and**<sup>2</sup> attempt to also bring her along to a place of
>   safety is to know that out of all the heroes with which history is here **and**<sup>3</sup>
>   there dotted, there is at least one, **and**<sup>4</sup> here we mean Sethra herself, who
>   has proven before the very eyes of history that her reputation is not
>   undeserved—that is, she consistently proves, ever **and**<sup>5</sup> anon, that she still
>   has all of those facets of character which won for her the renown she enjoys.

My goodness, you’d think there were no end to *and* — and<sup>1</sup>  no *and* to end (so to speak) — the way he just keeps  going and<sup>2</sup> going and<sup>3</sup> going and<sup>4</sup> going and<sup>5</sup> . . .

### A sentence with six *and*s:

> Therefore, in the interest of the satisfaction of our reader as well, we
>   must insist, of honesty, **and**<sup>1</sup> although we have not forgotten enemies,
>   plagues, invasions, wars, **and**<sup>2</sup> famine, we neverthless direct our reader’s
>   gaze to calm Aerich, happy Tazendra, **and**<sup>3</sup> smiling Pel, who, in turn, are
>   looking upon Khaavren **and**<sup>4</sup> Daro, who stare deeply into each other’s eyes
>   with the happy, tender, **and**<sup>5</sup> even joyful expression of fulfilled love, **and**<sup>6</sup> it is here that we choose to take our leave of the reader.

Well, there you have it then! I believe we can safely conclude that . . .

## There is no limit to the number of instances of *and* that you can have in a single sentence.

Comment: wow. beautifully answered! thanks for some inspiration!

Answer (score 0):

Ans to your first question: Yes. semi-colons can be used in a list. Have a look [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/semicolons.asp) for the rules.
For the second question, there is no rule that says there should be only one *and* in a sentence. For example:

> To be good at work and home, you need to manage your time and energy well.

Have some more reading about the topic [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60190/using-and-twice-in-a-list).