# Colon usage after an imperative sentence in survey instructions

Tags: questions, colons, imperatives

Consider a survey question that asks a question and then gives instruction about how to respond. For example,

> Is this a sample survey question? Check all that apply:
>
> __ yes
>
> __ no

Is it best practice to end "*Check all that apply*" with a colon because a list of options follows, or a period because the sentence giving instructions is finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that it is [at the very least](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/108630/41942) a good practice to separate an enumeration or an explanation and a clause that is to be enumerated or explained, with a colon. It acts like a logical separation of two parts.

Another thing worth mentioning is that a [bulleted list](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/15134/41942) should be treated differently: either list items should be separated with a semicolon, except for the last one terminated with a full stop, or each separate statement should be turned into a sentence with a capitalized letter and a full stop.