# How to avoid confusion when "and" is in a list

Tags: commas, lists

How do I avoid confusion when "and" is in a comma-separated list?

> E.g. "The guy eats, weighs a lot, and moves and jumps well."

If I don't use a serial comma, it would be:

> E.g. "The guy eats, weighs a lot and moves and jumps well."

As you can tell it may cause some confusion when "and" is part of a list.

Comment: A very similar question—[Comma before "and" which is being used after a list of other items containing other and/s](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233064/comma-before-and-which-is-being-used-after-a-list-of-items-containing-other-an/233067#233067)—was closed two years ago as a duplicate of [Should I put a comma before the last item in a list?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/412/should-i-put-a-comma-before-the-last-item-in-a-list) If yo believe that your question isn't a duplicate of the duplicate, please edit your answer to explain why it isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The practice of not using a serial comma when the last element is preceded by the word "and" often bothers me because these missing commas are very often spoken. When I read, I usually hear the printed text being spoken in my mind. So I would definitely add the serial comma, but as an editor I would not hesitate to add "he" to the third item in the series, which is to me a clause with a missing subject. Thus:

"The guy eats, weighs a lot, and he moves and jumps well."

Punctuation should be based not only on printed rules — the sound of the spoken words should also be a guide.