# Repetition of "and" in a list

Tags: repetition

Given the following sentence:

> I want you to join both the Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy
>   documents together by lunch time.

Is the repetition of "and" OK? Should I wrap my documents in quotation marks?

Comment: It seems to be OK!

Comment: Terms and Conditions is such a well known phrase that I think the reader can be relied upon to understand that it is one of the documents.

Comment: Or you could add the so-called Oxford comma: "the Terms and Conditions, and the Privacy Policy documents" to distinguish one document from the other.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using "and" twice in a list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60190/using-and-twice-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase *Terms and Conditions* is a widely known concept and probably won't cause confusion in your sentence. You could possibly wrap them in quotation marks to make clear that those words are the title of the document. Putting the words in *italic* would work as well.

If you really want to avoid the possible confusion here, you could also try inverting the order of the two coordinated phrases.

> I want you to join both the Privacy Policy and Terms and Conditions documents together by lunch time.

To me, this looks less likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 1):

While the sentence is grammatically fine and may not be ambiguous to someone familiar with the materials, there is a possibility of not nowing how many things you are talking about joining together. As noted by others, *terms and conditions* is a unified concept and would appear in one document. *Privacy policy* is another concept and, in this case, found in a separate document. You could clarify the number of documents by precediung each with the definite article *the*.

> I want you to join both **the** Terms and Conditions and **the** Privacy Policy documents together by lunch time.

A wordier approach would be to repeat *document* as well

> I want you to join both **the** Terms and Conditions **document** and **the** Privacy Policy **document** together by lunch time.

Probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically, everything looks good. But I agree that in terms of appearance the structure looks less than optimal.

Here are a few things you may want to consider:

1. If the message you're sending is an email, just use hyperlinks:

   > I want you to join both the [Terms and Conditions](http://#) and [Privacy Policy](http://#) documents together by lunch time.

   Hyperlinks are usually underlined by default (but not on this site) which adds greater emphasis and distinction.
2. If you want to really distinguish the terms in text only, use quotes and an ampersand:

   > I want you to join both the "Terms & Conditions" and "Privacy Policy" documents together by lunch time.

   You can also use **bold** or *italics* instead of quotation marks.

Hope this helps. Good luck!