# Using more than one "and" in a list

Tags: grammar

In a list, "and" is used once and at the end. Such as in "I went to the airport, hotel, **and** restaurant." But sometimes one item of the list includes two items in itself, so two "ands" appear. Such as in "Side effects include fatigue [one item] **and** nausea **and** vomiting [two items in one]." What is this called and should it be avoided?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repetition of "and" in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/265186/repetition-of-and-in-a-list) (It was closed for not including enough information or evidence of research, but still has some useful answers.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule that says you can only use a single "*and*" in a list. If one of the list elements contains "*and*", it's not ungrammatical to include it. Consider [the extreme example by Martin Gardner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_linguistic_example_sentences#Lexical_ambiguity):

> Wouldn't the sentence 'I want to put a hyphen between the words Fish and And and And and Chips in my Fish-And-Chips sign' have been clearer if quotation marks had been placed before Fish, and between Fish and and, and and and And, and And and and, and and and And, and And and and, and and and Chips, as well as after Chips?